# How do I convert an elf file from dwarf to stabs format?

Tags: c, file, debugging, elf, dwarf

Have a ELF debugging file.

The file uses the DWARF format.

How can I convert it into the stabs format?

Are there any tools or methods that may be helpful to do this?

Thank You.

Comment: Surely the easiest thing would be to recompile the source to use the "right" debug format, e.g. -gstabs
If that's not possible, perhaps compiling the debugger (gdb?) to understand both formats is an option?

Answer (score 1):

```
http://opensource.apple.com/source/binutils/binutils-20/src/binutils/wrstabs.c
```

is a link to code that extracts stabs information from ELF binaries.  It is long messy and problematic.

There really is no pre-built converter.  You would have to reverse engineer something like the code above.  As Mats suggested, consider recompiling.

However I am guessing you have a legacy binary with no code behind it. DWARF format was something Sun did about 10+ years ago, which was kind of a flop for Sun, IMO.

This is link on reverse engineering a binary into assembler.

```
http://www.linuxsa.org.au/meetings/reveng-0.2.pdf
```

Once you have assembler, in theory, you can build a new binary.  The problem is; entry points into extern functions and making them work with you linker correctly.  You will also have to remove the stuff related to DWARF. Then recompile linking stabs I guess

However the `http://dwarf.freestandards.org` site where the documentation lives appears to be permanently offline.

It would have helped my answer A LOT if I knew your hardware.

Comment: DWARF is the standard debug format for Linux x86-64 architecture at the very least. I'm pretty sure 32-bit Linux uses it too.

Comment: The DWARF standards web page is http://www.dwarfstd.org/ fwiw.  Agree with other posters - writing something that reads DWARF and outputs stabs is possible but I know of no such tool and it would be a lot of work.  stabs is a primitive, inefficient representation of debug information.  Watering down DWARF to stabs is not a great idea, I'd re-examine whatever requirements were leading you to this path.

Comment: @mats - Solaris (sparc and x86) is ELF, has DWARF, too.